# Display element when input value includes specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I created a form which contains input values of fruits items.
I want to display "box" on form confirm page if the users select "apple" on input page.

With code below, when the users select "greenapple", even if "apple" is not selected, box will be displayed as 'greenapple' includes 'apple'. This is not what I want.

```js
$('.box').hide();
if ($('#form-confirm input[name="fruits]').val().indexOf('apple') !== -1) {
  $('.box').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--input page -->
<form action="post" action="" id="form-input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="apple">Apple
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="greenapple">Green Apple
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana">Banana
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="peach">Peach
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lemon">Lemon
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="confirm">
</form>
<!--confirm page-->
<form action="post" action="" id="form-confirm">
  <input type="hidden" name="fruits" value="apple, greenapple..">
  <!--values you input on form input page-->
  <div class="box">
    box
  </div>
</form>
```

The results I want to get

```
apple => displays box
apple, greenapple => displays box
greenapple, banana => not displays box
```

Hope someone help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `==` instead of `indexOf()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the value from the input field and then properly check the input. Try the below code.

```
$('.box').hide();
let input = $('#form-confirm input[name="fruits').val();
const fruits = input.split(',');
const isApplePresent = fruits.some(fruit => fruit.trim() === 'apple')
if (isApplePresent) {
  $('.box').show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you require you could `split()` the string by the comma and use `some()` to determine if the resulting array contains the word you're looking for:

```js
$('#form-confirm input[name="fruits').on('input', e => {
  let containsApple = e.target.value.split(',').some(f => f.trim() === 'apple');
  $('.box').toggle(containsApple);
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-confirm">
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="greenapple" />
</form>

<div class="box">
  I appear when 'apple' is typed above
</div>
```